# AlarmManager with BroadcastReceiver - how is it meant to work?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, alarm, boot

I'm trying to make a task schedule app and I made an Alarm app trying to learn how to do that part at least. It uses `AlarmManager` and it makes an alarm go off at a time chosen by a `TimePicker`. But it doesn't work when the `emulator` is turned off and on again.

So I'm trying to use `BroadcastReceiver` but I don't understand any of the guides...I mean am I supposed to set the `intent` that the `alarm manager` does to the `BroadcastReciever`? Or can I just start up the app and then the alarm exists again or what? How are the alarms stored in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it doesn't work when the emulator is turned off and on again.

That is the correct behavior -- `AlarmManager`'s schedule is cleared on a reboot. You need to specifically register to receive the `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast, in order to re-establish your alarm events after a reboot.

> I mean am I supposed to set the intent that the alarm manager does to the BroadcastReciever?

Well, if you are using a `_WAKEUP`-style alarm, the recipe is to use a `getBroadcast()` `PendingIntent` with `AlarmManager`, where the `BroadcastReceiver` is either [a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) (and follows those instructions) or passes control to [my `WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful).

I have somewhat-contrived examples of using [`WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/Wakeful) and [`WakefulBroadcastRecevier`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/WakeCast).

> How are the alarms stored in android?

AFAIK, they are held in the memory of a core OS process and are not persisted.

Comment: I don't understand, how do I restart the same schedule that was created in the Alarm app (the user sets the alarm, it's not in the code) when the app is booted?

Comment: @user1780775: If you "made an Alarm app", then you need to save the alarm schedule yourself, in a file, database, `SharedPreferences`, "the cloud", etc. Then, on a reboot, you read that information in and use it to re-establish your `AlarmManager` events.

Comment: Does Alarm Manager gets cleared off when Android kills the processes due to low memory?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar: No, scheduled `AlarmManager` events are unaffected by normal process terminations.

Comment: @CommonsWare can you answer this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833785/alarm-manager-cache-cleaner-stops-app

Comment: @CommonsWare i was looking at it yesterday but don't have answer for it